# Joda DateTime output unexpected difference from gmt

Tags: datetime, jodatime, gmt

My code:

```
  val pattern = "MM-dd-yy"
  val t = DateTime.parse("07-01-86", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"))
  val z = t.getMillis.asInstanceOf[Long]
  println("ms= "+z) // expected output: 520560000000  actual output: 520578000000
```

Several online GMT date converters give a different millis output than DateTime.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution your **local time zone** is implicitly used when parsing the date time. You should use

```
val t = DateTime.parse("07-01-86", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withZoneUTC())
```

to force the `DateTime` to be created in the UTC zone. Then, the millis is `520560000000`. No need to execute `toDateTime(DateTimeZone)` on it any more.

Otherwise, with your construction

```
val t = DateTime.parse("07-01-86", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"))
```

the `DateTime` will be first created in your local TZ (ie. **midnight** of 07-01-86 in **your** TZ) and then "cast" to UTC, but preserving the timestamp (ie. it will be the same timestamp, but interpreted in UTC, so the time part and the day part will change depending on your local TZ offset).

*Example (my TZ is +02:00)*:

```
DateTime.parse("07-01-86", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern)) // --> 1986-07-01 00:00 (+02:00)
.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"))                         // --> 1986-06-30 22:00 (UTC)
```

I assumed you are OK with using `UTC` over `GMT` but there's also

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withZone(...)
```

where you can provide your desired zone.